# How to convert the object Text to Web Element?

Tags: java, selenium-webdriver, xpath

I want to verify this text (CORN only) and already found its location by using Xpath

But when I tried the `driver.findElementBy.xpath`
It said my xpath is an Object Text, not an element

Im using the selenium and java

My xpath is `//address/br/following-sibling::node()[1][self::text()[normalize-space()="A19"]`

(https://i.stack.imgur.com/EZfKo.png)
(https://i.stack.imgur.com/9CowN.png)

So is there any way to convert this one? I don't know how to make it as an Element or to find an Object text through `driver.`

Please HELPPPP ME THANKS

Comment: //address/br/following-sibling::node()[1] - This itself gives the value of the required text. No need to use the [self::text()[normalize-space()="A19"] here, because this one a Text in your context

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You shouldn't construct complicated xpath and get second text, using it.
Selenium can deal with `WebElements`, Corn is not `WebElement`, it's textContent of `address` element.

Instead of it, you just need to get text of `address` element, split it and assert second element from array (or store it).

```java
String text = driver.findElement(new By.ByTagName("address")).getText();
String[] address = text.split(System.lineSeparator());
Assert.assertEquals(address[1], "Corn");
```

Comment: `String[] newAddress = billChange.split(System.lineSeparator());
System.out.println(newAddress[2]); `

Thanks a lot this helped me out